# Advanced Numeric Control for jQuery or Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've been on the looking for a jQuery or AngularJS numeric control that does things like:

- Decimal formatting
- Currency Formatting
- Thousands formatting

along with the basic features in the HTML5 numeric control like:

- Min/Max
- Step
- Spinners

Anyone ran across anything like this?

Comment: not a complicated angular directive to create. Easy to find number format libraries and/or code for specific formats

Comment: Angular has native number and currency filters: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:currency http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:number

Comment: @RobJacobs I've seen the angular docs but I'd like to have it as you type rather than another element, if that makes sense.

Comment: Also, I'm a little surprised the HTML5 number input allows you to enter alpha chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up creating a directive that wraps a html5 numeric field with [a jquery numeric filter plugin](https://github.com/joshuadeleon/NumericInput)

Comment: you could also use my directive for numeric control: 
https://github.com/choroshin/angular-ui-numeric

Comment: @AlexChoroshin you should add the formatting options